# Joining multiple collections -MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 5 collections viz. claim,document,complaint,acknowledge,responses

relationship are as follows

1. claimid  of calim collection is foreign key in  document collection
2. documentid of document  is foreign key in  complaint collection
3. complaintid of complaint collection is foreignkey in acknowledge & responses collections

I need data from document collection and all its claim,complaint , responses and acknowledgement data

query used so far ,pls help in making query to fetch data from acknowledge & responses collections .

```
db.document.aggregate([ { $lookup: 
{ from: "complaint", localField: "documentid ", foreignField: "documentid", as: "ComplaintDetail" } },
{
        $lookup:{
            from: "Claim", 
            localField: "claimId", 
            foreignField: "claimId",
            as: "Claims"
        }
    }
])
```